# Autocomplete not passing extra value

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Iam using autocomplete for all my input fields like

```
$('input').autocomplete({              
      minLength: 1,                     
      source: "{site_url}publish/my_autocomplete"
});
```

it is working fine,but when I want to send the selected input id like

```
$('input').autocomplete({              
      minLength: 1,                     
      source: "{site_url}publish/my_autocomplete?key="+$(this).attr('id')
});
```

it is not working and key is undefined,can anyone suggest me for that

Comment: this will represent the selected input field

Comment: @Gautam3164 are you sure? you're not in any function, i would think it would still be the global object.

Comment: Actually it is under document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `this` doesn't represent the current `input` as you're assuming.
Try with this

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.autocomplete({              
      minLength: 1,                     
      source: "{site_url}publish/my_autocomplete?key=" + $this.attr('id')
    });
})
```